# Generating points for Sigmoid Function/Graph knowing only endpoints

Tags: functions

If I have 2 end points how can I generate values for the Sigmoid function?

Answer (score 1):

There is no **the** Sigmoid function.  [Sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) describes a class of functions, including the [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function), the [arctangent function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_function), the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), and others.

Even if you pick a particular sigmoid function, for instance, the logistic, merely picking two points on the curve is not specific enough -- the curve can always be scaled and translated infinitely many different ways to pass through the same two points.  For example, here are a few logistic curves (scaled and translated) to pass through the points $(-1,0)$ and $(1,1)$.

[image: several sigmoids with two points of common intersection]